# The usage of "one of" (singular/plural)

Tags: singular-vs-plural, superlatives, pluralia-tantum

> Jeans are one of the most common kinds of clothes.

Question: Does this sentence make sense? Is there anything to correct?

I am confused with singular and plural. The word "jeans" is plural, but "one" is a singular.

Comment: "Jeans", even in the plural, is just one *kind* of clothing. Does that make it easier to understand?